# Which posets can occur from commutative Frobenius algebras?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, posets

Let $A$ be a commutative Frobenius algebra. We can assume that $A$ is local and $A=K[x_i]/(I)$ for some variables $x_1,...,x_n$ and an admissible ideal.

Then the non-zero monomials $u_i$(including 1) form a basis of $A$ and we can look at the poset of submodules of the form $X_i=u_i A$.
(in case this is needed, assume $I$ only contains field elements 0,-1 and 1. Im not sure whether it might cause problems with regard to uniqueness when other field elements might be allowed).

This poset is bounded. For example when $A=K[x_1,...,x_n]/(x_i^2)$ then the poset is the Boolean lattice, but not every bounded poset can occur, for example when the top of the poset covers a unique elements then the poset must be a chain (and $A=K[x]/(x^n)$).

> Question: Is there a (homological) characterisation which posets can occur from commutative Frobenius algebras?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "$I$ only contains field elements $0$, $-1$, and $1$" ?

Comment: @ZachTeitler $I$ is generated by elements $r_i$ and in these relations you can only find field elements 0,1,-1. So for example $r_i=xyx$ is ok but $r_i=xyx-3*yxy$ not. But Im not sure whether this matters, probably not.